# Disconnected Wi-Fi capability

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, audio

I saw an earlier post thinking that it would help, but it didn't. The post was for turning the Wi-Fi capability on, which is what I needed, but in the command it shows that it's already enabled, just disconnected. I tried putting "connected" at the end instead of "enabled", but it told me it was invalid. The computer already has Wi-Fi capability, it just got messed up in the switch back to Win7. The computer is a Toshiba Satellite U305-S5077. It was bought used with Win8 on it and the sound card broke (or stopped working). The toshiba website only had drivers for Win7 and Vista for that laptop so I went ahead and downgraded to Win7. After that, the Wi-Fi went out and the sound is still gone. I re-tried the Toshiba.com support drivers but it failed, and failed, and failed. I have pictures of the problem but since I'm new to the site I'm not able to show it.

Also, if you have any knowledge on the sound issue, that would be very much appreciated! :)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please do not put external contact information in your questions. All comments and answers should be done here so the other people in this community can learn from it too.

Comment: This laptop model appears to be fairly old. It sounds like some components are failing. Is the wireless antenna switch turned on?

Comment: It says it's enabled but disconnected. When I try turning it on it says it can't because something is wrong with the driver. I used the troubleshooter to try and find out what was wrong, but it just told me that the problem is that it was turned off. The only solution was to turn it back on. I've tried turning it on through the command prompt, and the Windows Mobility Center, which is where I usually turn my Wi-Fi on and off. My original thought was that the parts were just old and broke apart or something, but that thought changed after I switched the OS.

Comment: From what I saw in the manual, there is a physical switch (button) used to turn the antenna on and off. The software can not actuate a physical switch in your case. So, look for a button with an antenna symbol next to it. Lastly, if your parts are "old and broke", switching OS is not going to change that. They will still be old and broke.

Comment: Awesome! I saw that I while ago but wasn't thinking about it for some reason...Thanks SO much! :) Would you happen to know anything about the sound? Plugging in headphones or speakers doesn't help either.

Comment: Did you get the WiFi to work? If so, I will place it as an answer below. As far as sound, you need to ask another question for that.

Comment: Yes, it did! The Wi-Fi is working perfectly, thanks. :) Alright then I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I saw in the manual, there is a physical switch (button) used to turn the antenna on and off. The software can not actuate a physical switch in your case. So, look for a button with an antenna symbol next to it. Lastly, if your parts are "old and broke", switching OS is not going to change that. They will still be old and broke.